# Show hidden input javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is the hidden form not shown when it looses focus? The alert is coming up nicely when leaving the input but the other hidden form is still not there.

**html**

```
<body>
   <input type="text" id="myinput" value="">
   <input type="hidden" id="validation_message_email" value="enter a valid email">
</body>
```

**javascript**

```
window.onload = function() {
   $("#myinput").blur(myAlert);
};

function myAlert() {
   alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
   $("#validation_message_email").show();
}
```

Comment: Its hidden element notice `type="hidden"` I think you need `<span style="display:none" id="validation_message_email">enter a valid emai</span>`

Comment: why have you taken "validation_message_email"  hidden?

Comment: `type='hidden'` doesn't directly implies that the element is hidden, it means the control itself is a type known as 'hidden'. You cannot change it, so its recommended you use a `<div>` or `<span>` tag, set the css as `display:none` initially, and then later call the jquery `show()` function on the element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't display a hidden input like that.A span will suit better for this purpose,

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="">
<span style="display:none"  id="validation_message_email">enter a valid email</span>
```

Comment: Indeed. An `<input>` should be used for getting input from a user, not for displaying a message.

Comment: You should  start with `style="display:none" ` or else there is no need of `.show()`

Comment: @Satpal thanks for the suggetion. Just edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`validation_message_email` doesn't have its `display` style property as `none`, so show() will not make it visible from `type="hidden"`.

You need to replace

```
$("#validation_message_email").show();
```

with

```
$("#validation_message_email").attr( "type", "text" );
```

However, **if** the intent is to only show a message, then you don't need to use a hidden input for the same.

```
<body>
   <input type="text" id="myinput" value="">
</body>
```

and

```
window.onload = function() {
   $("#myinput").blur(function(){
      alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
      $(this).append('<span id="emailValidationMessage">enter a valid email</span>')
   });
   $("#myinput").focus(function(){
      $("#emailValidationMessage").remove();
   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `type="hidden"` as hidden elements are not `display:none` they are hidden by default.

Use `type="text"` and hide it with css and show where you want

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="validation_message_email" value="enter a valid email">

<script>   
window.onload = function() {
    $("#myinput").blur(myAlert);
};

function myAlert() {
   $("#validation_message_email").attr("type","text");
}
</script>
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/PunitSoniME/pe8f7k5r/), it might help you.

```js
$("#myinput").blur( function(){

myAlert();

});

function myAlert() {
   $("#validation_message_email").attr("type", "text");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="validation_message_email" value="enter a valid email">
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="form-group" id="usernamediv">

 <input class="form-control" name="username" id="username"
     placeholder="Username" type="text"  required=""> </div>
 <div class="form-group" id="passworddiv">
  <input name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"  type="password" required="">
  </div>
<button id="#loginButton">Login</button>
<button id="#forgotpassword">Forgot Password</button>


<script>
$("#forgotpassword").hide();
$("#forgotpassword").click(function(e){
$("#loginButton").hide();
$("#usernamediv").show();
$("#passworddiv").hide();
})


</script>
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.